# DataFrame to breeze DenseMatrix in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, eigenvalue, covariance-matrix

I'm trying to convert a dataframe to a breeze dense matrix using scala. I couldn't find any built-in functions to do this, so here's what I'm doing.

```
import scala.util.Random
import breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix

val featuresDF = (1 to 10)
    .map(_ => (
      Random.nextDouble,Random.nextDouble,Random.nextDouble))
    .toDF("F1", "F2", "F3")

var FeatureArray: Array[Array[Double]] = Array.empty
val features = featuresDF.columns

for(i <- features.indices){
    FeatureArray = FeatureArray :+ featuresDF.select(features(i)).collect.map(_(0).toString).map(_.toDouble)
}

val desnseMat = DenseMatrix(FeatureArray: _*).t
```

This does work fine and I get what I want. However, this causes OOM exceptions in my environment. Is there a better way of doing this conversion. My ultimate goal is to calculate the eigen values and eigen vectors of the features using the dense matrix.

```
import breeze.stats.covmat
import breeze.linalg.eig

val covariance = covmat(desnseMat)
val eigen = eig(covariance)
```

So, it would be even better if there's a direct way to get the eigen values and eigen vectors from the dataframe. PCA in spark ml must be doing this calculation using the features column. Is there a way to access eigen values through PCA?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to increase your RAM.

Secondly, try one of these functions, using DenseMatrix in Spark. 
Both functions use the same amount of RAM on my computer.

I obtained 1,34 seconds for parsing 201238 rows in a DataFrame with 1 column each containing several Double values:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseMatrix
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def getDenseMatrixFromDF(featuresDF:DataFrame):DenseMatrix = {
    val featuresTrain = featuresDF.columns
    val rows = featuresDF.count().toInt

    val newFeatureArray:Array[Double] = featuresTrain
       .indices
       .flatMap(i => featuresDF
       .select(featuresTrain(i))
       .collect())
       .map(r => r.toSeq.toArray).toArray.flatten.flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector].values)

    val newCols = newFeatureArray.length / rows
    val denseMat:DenseMatrix = new DenseMatrix(rows, newCols, newFeatureArray, isTransposed=false)
    denseMat
}
```

If I want to get a DenseVector from a DataFrame with one column containing one Double value only, I got 0.8 seconds for the same amount of data :

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def getDenseVectorFromDF(featuresDF:DataFrame):DenseVector = {
    val featuresTrain = featuresDF.columns
    val cols = featuresDF.columns.length

    cols match {
      case i if i>1 => throw new IllegalArgumentException
      case _ => {
        def addArray(acc:Array[Array[Double]],cur:Array[Double]):Array[Array[Double]] = {
          acc :+ cur
        }

        val newFeatureArray:Array[Double] = featuresTrain
          .indices
          .flatMap(i => featuresDF
          .select(featuresTrain(i))
          .collect())
          .map(r => r.toSeq.toArray.map(e => e.asInstanceOf[Double])).toArray.flatten

        val denseVec:DenseVector = new DenseVector(newFeatureArray)
        denseVec
   }
}
```

To compute eigenvalues/eigenvectors just check [this link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/mllib-dimensionality-reduction.html) and [this API link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/EigenValueDecomposition.html)

To compute covariance matrix chek [this link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/mllib-basics.html) and [this API link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/RowMatrix.html#computeCovariance())

Answer (score 1):

```
def getDenseMatrixFromDF(featuresDF:DataFrame):BDM[Double] = {
    val featuresTrain = featuresDF.columns
    val cols = featuresTrain.length
    val rows = featuresDF.count().toInt
    val denseMat: BDM[Double] = BDM.tabulate(rows,cols)((i, j)=>{
        featuresDF.collect().apply(i).getAs[Double](j)
        })
    denseMat
  }
```

Comment: please explain your solution rather than just sharing the code

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Catalina Chiru's answer I modified it to work which 2D datasets because their first method was giving me error.

```
import breeze.linalg.{DenseMatrix, DenseVector}
import breeze.stats.regression.leastSquares

def getDenseMatrixFromDF(featuresDF: DataFrame): DenseMatrix[Double] = {
    val columnNames = featuresDF.columns
    val rows = featuresDF.count().toInt

    val newFeatureArray = columnNames
      .indices
      .flatMap(i => featuresDF
        .select(columnNames(i))
        .collect()).map(r => r.getDouble(0)).toArray

    val newCols = newFeatureArray.length / rows
    val denseMat: DenseMatrix[Double] = new DenseMatrix[Double](rows, newCols, newFeatureArray)
    denseMat
  }
```